# Android adding more widgets with different content

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to create an application with a widget. When the user places the widget on the desktop a listview should come up with a list of items. The user selects an item then the widget is created with the respective text related to that item. For simplicity I am using now an alertdialog. The input text should appear only in the widget I create. It should not appear in the other widgets. How am I supposed to do that? I have not found anyhing about this.

The AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.i("INFO", "AppWidgetProvider"); 

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),   UpdateWidgetService.class);
        //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
        //context.startService(intent);
            Intent intentA = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NoteListToWidget.class);
    intentA.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentA);

        }

}
```

The service:

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
    String value;
    Dialog dialog_newitem;


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i("INFO", "UpdateWidgetService");

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

        int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));
            String v = GlobalVars.getValue();
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, v);

            Intent configIntent = new Intent(this, Notepad.class);
            configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
            PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetlayout, configPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();

        super.onStart(intent, startId);


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the Activity with the AlertDialog (the latter listview):

```
public class NoteListToWidget extends Activity {

    Dialog dialog_newitem;
    EditText et_newitem;
    String value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        dialog_newitem = new Dialog(NoteListToWidget.this);
        dialog_newitem.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_productlists_grp_capitalized);
        dialog_newitem.setTitle("Select");
        dialog_newitem.setCancelable(true);

        et_newitem = (EditText) dialog_newitem.findViewById(R.id.et_item_name);

        Button btn_Save = (Button) dialog_newitem.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_pr);
        btn_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                value = et_newitem.getText().toString();
                 GlobalVars.setValue(value);
                dialog_newitem.dismiss();
                /*
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
                serviceIntent.setAction("com.myapp.app.UpdateWidgetService");
                startService(serviceIntent);
                */
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoteListToWidget.this, com.myapp.app.UpdateWidgetService.class);
                startService(intent);

            }
            });


        Button btn_Cancel = (Button) dialog_newitem.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_pr);
        btn_Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog_newitem.dismiss();
            }

        });
        dialog_newitem.show();



    }

}
```

I don't how and from where should I call the NoteListToWidget activity and how to make this whole thing work.

Comment: listview not appearing in you widget?

Comment: For now, it is just a dialog. When I create the widget the dialog appears, but the main activity opens up in the background. Why does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is impossible to answer your question in full. This is because it seems you are missing a lot of things about how app-widgets are working, so you must read more about them. However I will give you a place to start.

The onUpdate method of the AppWidgetProvider is called each time an app-widget that **it is already placed** on the desktop needs an update. That is, even if you manage to display your list from there and the user cancels the operation there is NO way to remove your app-widget from the onUpdate method.
Furthermore when the onUpdate method finishes the AppWidgetProvider is destroyed, so even if you manage to display your list from there there is NO way to get the items that user selected. Long story short, you **canNOT** do it from onUpdate method and you **canNOT** do it by this approach.

However, you **CAN do it** by using a configuration activity in a specified point of the app-widget's creation process but this cannot be answered in the context of your question because you must first understand how the app-widget system works in Android. The best place to start is [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). I had the same problems with my first app-widget application (and almost the same concerns with you) but then I started to read and read, finally after 1.5 months I 've managed to make something like the thing you want to do. So don't say

> How am I supposed to do that? I have not found anyhing about this

and start reading, this is the life with Android. It's all in the above link, there are also very good open-source projects in google code [like this weather widget](http://code.google.com/p/yaww/) which allows the user to configure it BEFORE it is placed on the desktop.

Hope this helps...

Comment: The configuration activity explains everything. I found it 2 hrs after posting this question. With that I could set my foot on the right way. I suggest everyone having this problem to watch the 160-167 videos of thenewboston on youtube. It is easy and it took an hour for me to figure out what my problem/bad concept was. Thank you Christos!